# php find and replace using string using wildcards

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have strings in my html like this `>> &rf=238255238255238255`

So thats  `>>      &rf=` (and 18 random digits)

How do I find that with a view to replacing it with `...` ?

My own `&rf=0101010101010101`

Comment: [`preg_replace( '/&rf=\d{18}/', $repl, $text )`](https://regex101.com/r/qM2rQ1/2)

Comment: @jersten sure about edit? see the OP try example...

Comment: Yes I see now. Scott: if you want match even ‘greater-than’ change pattern in /`>>\s+&rf=\d{18}/` ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can capture it using regex and replace it whatever value you want.

Your regex will be `"/(?<=&rf=)\\d+/"`

```
$re = "/(?<=&rf=)\\d+/"; 
$str = ">> &rf=238255238255238255"; 
$subst = ""; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sH9dO5/2) here.

Comment: OK that was perfect :) I dont get regex at all so thanks for that demo link.